# Can Google Cloud Run be used to run a continuously-listening Python script?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'd like to run a Python script in the cloud. It would use [Tweepy Streaming](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.10.0/streaming_how_to.html) to continuously listen for Tweets containing certain keywords. So it needs to run **uninterrupted, 24/7**.

Would Google Cloud Run be suitable for this use case?

The [Quotas and Limits](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas) page mentions that requests timeout after 60 minutes max, but I don't know exactly what this means.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it would not be a good choice.  Serverless infrastructure provided by products like Cloud Run and Cloud Functions is generally assumed to expand and contract server instances on demand, and server instances are never guaranteed a long uptime.  If you absolutely require 24/7 uninterrupted operation of some background task not tied to an event or HTTP request, you should use a different cloud product, such as App Engine or Compute Engine.

Comment: Understood. Thanks. Yes, it does need to run continuously. Otherwise, I imagine Cloud Run + Cloud Scheduler would have been a good option. If I was considering Cloud Run, it's mostly because it seems relatively simple, and my service already Dockerized. But after some research, Container-Optimized OS images on Cloud Compute seem to be similar and capable of sustaining continuous operation.

Answer (score 0):

"some background task not tied to an event or HTTP request"
Isn't what the OP wants? Merely to listen for tweets 24/7? Detecting a tweet is an event and an HTTP request. Cloud Run and Cloud Functions can be triggered 24/7 via its URL endpoints.

In the [Cloud Functions Page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/), if you scroll down there is a section called "Integration with third-party services and APIs".

I quote this section:
"... capabilities such as sending a confirmation email after a successful Stripe payment or responding to Twilio text message events"

listening for tweets counts too. So it seems Google Cloud Functions/ Cloud Run can be used for the OP's use case.